# Parsing bank statement and returning values from 2d array

Tags: ruby, arrays, parsing, nokogiri, watir

I'm trying to parse my online bank statement, retrieve the values, and then get the individual values. Here's a sample statement. `otherrefcode` stands for the money I sent, and `refcode` stands for the money I received.

```
  Date      Description Type [?]    In (£)  Out (£) Balance (£)
29 Aug 13   person1 otherrefcode 29AUG13 18:23  FPO     42.81   662.68
29 Aug 13   person2 otherrefcode 29AUG13 18:21  FPO     599.91  705.49
29 Aug 13   person3 refcode     TFR     30.80   1,305.40
28 Aug 13   person4 otherrefcode 28AUG13 14:23  FPO     25.27   1,336.20
28 Aug 13   person5 refcode     TFR     41.08   1,361.47
```

And here's my ruby code. How do I grab the individual values?

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'

def toprice(data)
    data.to_s.match(/\d\d\.\d\d/).to_s
end

$browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
$browser.goto("bankurl")
$page_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html)

table_array = Array.new
table = $browser.table(:class,'statement smartRewardsOffers')
table.rows.each do |row|
    row_array = Array.new
    row.cells.each do |cell|
        row_array << cell.text
    end
    table_array << row_array
end
puts "1strun"
puts table_array[1..4][1]
puts "2ndrun"
puts table_array[1][1..4]
```

That outputs

```
1strun
person1 otherrefcode 29AUG13 18:23
FPO

42.81
2ndrun
29 Aug 13
person2 otherrefcode 29AUG13 18:21
FPO

599.91
705.49
```

The HTML of the statement (well, the first 3 transactions - warning, 76 lines long.)

```
<table id="pnlgrpStatement:conS1:tblTransactionListView" class="statement smartRewardsOffers" summary="Table displaying the statement for your account Classic xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="{sorter:false} first" scope="col">
<form id="pnlgrpStatement:conS1:tblTransactionListView:frmToggle" class="validationName:(pnlgrpStatement:conS1:tblTransactionListView:frmToggle) validate:()" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" autocomplete="off" action="/personal/a/viewproductdetails/ViewProductDetails.jsp" method="post" name="pnlgrpStatement:conS1:tblTransactionListView:frmToggle">
<input id="pnlgrpStatement:conS1:tblTransactionListView:frmToggle:btnASCSortStatements" class="tableSorter tableSorterReverse" type="image" title="Sort by oldest first" alt="Sort by oldest first" src="/wps/wcm/connect/xxxxxxxxxxxx/sort_arrow_up-8-1375113571.png?MOD=AJPERES&CACHEID=xxxxxxxxxxx" name="pnlgrpStatement:conS1:tblTransactionListView:frmToggle:btnASCSortStatements">
 Date
 <input type="hidden" value="pnlgrpStatement:conS1:tblTransactionListView:frmToggle" name="pnlgrpStatement:conS1:tblTransactionListView:frmToggle">
 <input type="hidden" value="xxxxxxx" name="submitToken">
<input type="hidden" name="hasJS" value="true">
</form>
</th>
<th class="{sorter:false} description" scope="col">Description</th>
<th class="{sorter:false} transactionType" scope="col">
Type 
<span class="cxtHelp">
<a class="cxtTrigger" href="#transForView" title="Click to find out more about transaction types">[?]</a>
</span>
</th>
<th class="{sorter:false} numeric" scope="col">In (£)</th>
<th class="{sorter:false} numeric" scope="col">Out (£)</th>
<th class="{sorter:false} numeric" scope="col">Balance (£)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="alt">
<th class="first">29 Aug 13</th>
<td>
<span class="splitString">person1</span>
<span class="splitString"> </span>
<span class="splitString">ref</span>
<span class="splitString"> </span>
<span class="splitString">29AUG13 18:23</span>
<span class="splitString"> </span>
</td>
<td>
<abbr title="Faster Payments Outgoing">FPO</abbr>
</td>
<td class="numeric"></td>
<td class="numeric">42.81</td>
<td class="numeric">662.68</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="first">29 Aug 13</th>
<td>
<span class="splitString">person2</span>
<span class="splitString"> </span>
<span class="splitString">ref</span>
<span class="splitString"> </span>
<span class="splitString">29AUG13 18:21</span>
<span class="splitString"> </span>
</td>
<td>
<abbr title="Faster Payments Outgoing">FPO</abbr>
</td>
<td class="numeric"></td>
<td class="numeric">599.91</td>
<td class="numeric">705.49</td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<th class="first">29 Aug 13</th>
<td>
<span class="splitString">person3</span>
<span class="splitString"> </span>
<span class="splitString">ref>
</td>
<td>
<abbr title="Transfer">TFR</abbr>
</td>
<td class="numeric"></td>
<td class="numeric">30.80</td>
<td class="numeric">1,305.40</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: I want to get the values, for example "FPO" or "person1" or "599.91"

Comment: Remember that watir is working with the html of the page. Without the html, it is very difficult to provide help. Please give the actual table html (though you can change the text if there is anything sensitive).

Comment: Ok, done, posting into the question, sorry about the length. I x'ed out anything personal.

Answer (score 0):

You have already gotten the text of each cell into the `table_array`. You just need to get the right cell. It is a 2D array, so the first index is the row and the second index is the column. Note that the array is 0-based index (ie 0 represents the first row/column).

```
# type in the first row
puts table_array[1][2]
#=> "FPO"

# person in the first row
puts table_array[1][1].split[0]
#=> "person2"

# out value in the second row
puts table_array[2][4]
#=> "599.91"
```

Working with these indicies is not so nice. As well, the splitting of the description column is harder at this point. Instead, I would suggest creating a hash for each row.

```
table_array = Array.new
table_rows = $browser.table(:class,'statement smartRewardsOffers')
table_rows.rows.to_a[1..-1].each do |row|
  row_hash = Hash.new
  row_hash[:date] = row.cell(:index => 0).text
  row_hash[:person] = row.cell(:index => 1).span(:index => 0).text
  row_hash[:code] = row.cell(:index => 1).span(:index => 2).text rescue ''
  row_hash[:time] = row.cell(:index => 1).span(:index => 4).text rescue ''
  row_hash[:type] = row.cell(:index => 2).text
  row_hash[:in] = row.cell(:index => 3).text
  row_hash[:out] = row.cell(:index => 4).text
  row_hash[:balance] = row.cell(:index => 5).text
  table_array << row_hash
end

# First data row's information
row = 0 # Note that the rows are 0-based index
puts table_array[row][:date] #=> "29 Aug 13"
puts table_array[row][:person] #=> "person1"
puts table_array[row][:code] #=> "ref"
puts table_array[row][:time] #=> "29AUG13 18:23"
puts table_array[row][:type] #=> "FPO"
puts table_array[row][:in] #=> ""
puts table_array[row][:out] #=> "42.81"
puts table_array[row][:balance] #=> "662.68"
```